# Showing volume differences

Tags: integration

Is there a good explanation to why two curves with the same area when revolved around the $y$-axis, have different volumes? I know that this is due to a difference in radius of the curves from the $y$-axis. However is there a more detailed explanation? I do not know how I can go about explaining this concept with detail and accuracy.

Comment: Most shapes with the same volume have different areas though, however they are generated - finding two shapes with the same area and volume might be hard!

Comment: Why do two points sweep out circles with different circumferences when revolved around the $y$-axis?

Comment: Roughly speaking, for the same reason why two bodies with the same mass may have different moments of inertia.

Answer (score 1):

Two areas can have very different distributions relative to their proximity to the y axis. The part of the area closest to the y axis will not revolve as far and so generate less volume. Therefore shapes that have most of their area skewed towards the y axis will generate less volume and vice versa. Shapes with their area skewed away from the y axis will generate more volume.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of a good counterexample.

The cross sections (that is, the area between the two curves) could have congruent shapes, not just equal areas, and still result in very different volumes when rotated.

Take a unit square with vertices at (0,0), (0,1), (1,1), and (1,0).  Rotate that around the y-axis and you get a cylinder with a volume of $\pi$.

But take a unit square with vertices at (1,0), (1,1), (2,1), and (2,0).  Rotate that around the y-axis and you get a cylindrical shell with a volume of $3\pi$.